# How to wait for a specific amount of time between iterations in a for loop in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I'm making a program that shows different parts of an image in the same ImageView. But it should wait for some amount of time, about 500 milliseconds, between any two image changes.
Like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<=4;i++){
  for(int j=1;j<=4;j++){
  //code to refresh the image.
  // wait for 500 milliseconds before resuming the normal iteration
  }
}
```

I tried using the following code:

```
for(int i=1; i<=4;i++){
  for(int j=1;j<=4;j++){
    //code to refresh the image.
    Thread.sleep(500);
  }
}
```

But this displays only the last segment of the image, not segment by segment. BTW, each segment is saved as pic1, pic2,pic3.. and so on (they all are different images). I want a solution to display them in the following sequence:

- pic1
- wait for 500 ms
- pic2
- wait for 500 ms
- pic3
- ... and so on

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 3):

If this is inside your UI thread loop, you should use an `AsyncTask` or a `Timer` to achieve your goals instead, to avoid blocking the UI.

Using `AsyncTask`:

```
class UpdateImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // refresh the image here
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                // NOTE: Cannot call UI methods directly here.
                // Call them from onProgressUpdate.
                publishProgress(i, j);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch(InterruptedException) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    }
}
```

then just call

```
new UpdateImages().execute();
```

when you want to start this task. Using an `AsyncTask` this way avoids blocking your UI, and still lets you do whatever you want on schedule.

Comment: Note that `Thread.sleep` throws `InterruptedException`. You should surround that sentence with a try/catch block code.

Comment: Good catch. I knew I forgot something :)

Comment: one question, should i include this class inside my activity.java class, or declare it outside in the same package??

Comment: i dont have any other fucntion that should take place in the background. so, will this code block the other functions from being called??? i mean, i dont want any other process to be running while the image changing is going on..???

Comment: An AsyncTask can be declared either as an inner class or as a separate class. Since this one manipulates images, it may be easier to make it an inner class, but that decision is up to you. `AsyncTask` runs in its own thread, so it won't block anything else.